# Query a table and divide a column value by the column value of a second table, for a specified date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In Query 1 below I'm looking to query a pricing table by date, hour, price (lmp), etc.  The price will be in pesos and I want to convert to dollars, so in Query 2 I'm pulling exchange rates by date and exchange rate price.

For accounting purposes I need to use the exchange rate price from the previous date of execution.  So for tomorrow, I would use today's exchange rate.  Is this possible to do in SQL?

An image of the result from Query 1 and 2 has been provided below.  And I have also provided an image of desired results.  Essentially the lmp column from Query 1, divided by the exchange rate column from Query 2.

```
    DECLARE @dateLb1  DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -1,GETDATE()+1);
    DECLARE @dateNext DATE = GETDATE()+1;
    
    -- Query 1
    SELECT n.node_name, c.ca_name, d.dt, d.hr, d.lmp, d.mcc, d.mcl
    FROM mx.bca_da_lmp AS d
    INNER JOIN mx.node_list AS n
        ON d.node_id = n.node_id
    INNER JOIN mx.control_areas AS c
        ON n.ca_id =  c.ca_id
    WHERE d.dt = @dateNext
            AND n.node_name = '07OMS-230'
    ORDER BY c.ca_name ASC, n.node_name ASC, d.dt ASC, d.hr ASC
    
    -- Query 2
    SELECT x.dt, x.exchange_rate
    FROM mx.us_to_mx_exchange_rate AS x
    WHERE x.dt = @dateLb1
    ORDER BY x.dt ASC
```

```
    node_name   ca  dt          hr     lmp      mcc         mcl
    07OMS-230   BCA 2021-06-30  1   772.190000  0.000000    1.950000
    07OMS-230   BCA 2021-06-30  2   569.370000  0.000000    1.490000
    07OMS-230   BCA 2021-06-30  3   555.020000  0.000000    1.520000
    07OMS-230   BCA 2021-06-30  4   564.520000  0.000000    1.590000
    07OMS-230   BCA 2021-06-30  5   1288.390000 0.000000    1.550000
    07OMS-230   BCA 2021-06-30  6   1320.820000 0.000000    3.220000
    07OMS-230   BCA 2021-06-30  7   569.760000  0.000000    1.230000
    07OMS-230   BCA 2021-06-30  8   620.850000  0.000000    1.100000
    07OMS-230   BCA 2021-06-30  9   1257.650000 0.000000    2.160000
    07OMS-230   BCA 2021-06-30  10  1257.240000 0.000000    1.120000
    07OMS-230   BCA 2021-06-30  11  1281.800000 0.000000    0.220000
    07OMS-230   BCA 2021-06-30  12  1352.180000 0.000000    3.420000
    07OMS-230   BCA 2021-06-30  13  1331.700000 0.000000    4.460000
    07OMS-230   BCA 2021-06-30  14  1593.780000 0.000000    3.970000
    07OMS-230   BCA 2021-06-30  15  1615.230000 0.000000    8.770000
    07OMS-230   BCA 2021-06-30  16  1812.260000 0.000000    6.480000
    07OMS-230   BCA 2021-06-30  17  1822.560000 0.000000    4.690000
    07OMS-230   BCA 2021-06-30  18  1935.100000 0.000000    7.280000
    07OMS-230   BCA 2021-06-30  19  2282.440000 0.000000    13.420000
    07OMS-230   BCA 2021-06-30  20  1102.800000 0.000000    6.440000
    07OMS-230   BCA 2021-06-30  21  1132.110000 0.000000    6.650000
    07OMS-230   BCA 2021-06-30  22  1138.730000 0.000000    6.130000
    07OMS-230   BCA 2021-06-30  23  1576.370000 0.000000    5.700000
    07OMS-230   BCA 2021-06-30  24  905.230000  0.000000    3.760000
```

```
    dt          exchange_rate
    2021-06-29  19.81570
```

```
    node_name   ca  dt          hr    lmp   ex_rate   lmp_usd
    07OMS-230   BCA 6/30/2021   1   772.19  19.8157 38.96859561
    07OMS-230   BCA 6/30/2021   2   569.37  19.8157 28.73327715
    07OMS-230   BCA 6/30/2021   3   555.02  19.8157 28.00910389
    07OMS-230   BCA 6/30/2021   4   564.52  19.8157 28.48852173
    07OMS-230   BCA 6/30/2021   5   1288.39 19.8157 65.01864683
    07OMS-230   BCA 6/30/2021   6   1320.82 19.8157 66.65522793
    07OMS-230   BCA 6/30/2021   7   569.76  19.8157 28.75295851
    07OMS-230   BCA 6/30/2021   8   620.85  19.8157 31.33121717
    07OMS-230   BCA 6/30/2021   9   1257.65 19.8157 63.46735165
    07OMS-230   BCA 6/30/2021   10  1257.24 19.8157 63.44666098
    07OMS-230   BCA 6/30/2021   11  1281.8  19.8157 64.68608225
    07OMS-230   BCA 6/30/2021   12  1352.18 19.8157 68.23781143
    07OMS-230   BCA 6/30/2021   13  1331.7  19.8157 67.20428751
    07OMS-230   BCA 6/30/2021   14  1593.78 19.8157 80.43016396
    07OMS-230   BCA 6/30/2021   15  1615.23 19.8157 81.51263897
    07OMS-230   BCA 6/30/2021   16  1812.26 19.8157 91.45576487
    07OMS-230   BCA 6/30/2021   17  1822.56 19.8157 91.97555474
    07OMS-230   BCA 6/30/2021   18  1935.1  19.8157 97.65488981
    07OMS-230   BCA 6/30/2021   19  2282.44 19.8157 115.1834152
    07OMS-230   BCA 6/30/2021   20  1102.8  19.8157 55.65284093
    07OMS-230   BCA 6/30/2021   21  1132.11 19.8157 57.13197111
    07OMS-230   BCA 6/30/2021   22  1138.73 19.8157 57.46604965
    07OMS-230   BCA 6/30/2021   23  1576.37 19.8157 79.5515677
    07OMS-230   BCA 6/30/2021   24  905.23  19.8157 45.6824639
```

Comment: Please show sample data + desired results (as formatted text).

Comment: It's possible provided you have the required data. Is `x.dt` the date required? I have no idea, you need to provide the complete sample data and expected results.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time posting.  Are the images I added not helpful?

Comment: And work on a [mre] with the emphasis on minimal, its unlikely it takes that much data to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the tips everyone.  Again, this is my first time posting.

Comment: FYI its not best practice to use `GETDATE()+1` as its not standard SQL nor is it obvious what unit +1 is. You should always use `dateadd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you wish to combine the two queries to give you the price in the dollars. You can use `CROSS APPLY` to do that. And rather than calculating multiple dates in advance I would just calculate it as part of the query as shown. That way the query will continue to work even if you wanted to include multiple dates at some point in the future.

You also would appear to need a `TOP 1` on your exchange rate table query since you have an `ORDER BY` which implies there are multiple rows per currency.

```
--DECLARE @dateLb1 DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()+1);
DECLARE @dateNext DATE = DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE());

SELECT n.node_name, c.ca_name, d.dt, d.hr, d.lmp, d.mcc, d.mcl
  , d.lmp / ex.exchange_rate PriceInDollars
FROM mx.bca_da_lmp AS d
INNER JOIN mx.node_list AS n ON d.node_id = n.node_id
INNER JOIN mx.control_areas AS c ON n.ca_id =  c.ca_id
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 x.exchange_rate
  FROM mx.us_to_mx_exchange_rate AS x
  WHERE x.dt = DATEADD(DAY, -1, d.dt)--@dateLb1
  ORDER BY x.dt ASC
) ex
WHERE d.dt = @dateNext
AND n.node_name = '07OMS-230'
ORDER BY c.ca_name ASC, n.node_name ASC, d.dt ASC, d.hr ASC;
```